# How does Lindley compare a Bayes factor and a p-value?

Tags: p-value, model-selection, bayes-factors

I was reading [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-wine-economics/article/analysis-of-a-wine-tasting/E87C88D4A82E2B2D355AE3B641B5E8F8) by Dennis Lindley ("Analysis of a Wine Tasting", J. Wine Econ. 2006). Statistically, the paper is a straightforward analysis of a $10\times 11$ two-way table. To test whether a certain effect is significant, Lindley computes both a p-value using the F-test and a Bayes factor.

However, I don't understand the final paragraph in the paper, of which the last few sentences are:

> It will readily be seen that the Bayes factor is more conservative than the F-test. For example, take the one degree of freedom for France versus the States in the Cabernet table (13). The F-test is significant at 0.1%, or 0.001. The Bayes factor is only 0.020, *20 times greater*.

(Emphasis mine.) This suggests that the Bayes factor and the p-value can be compared on the same scale. How can this be?